# getting yearmonth date format in sparksql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get year month column using this function:

```
date_format(delivery_date,'mmmmyyyy')
```

but I'm getting wrong values for the month
ex.

[image]

example of the output I want to get:

if I have this date `16-9-2020` I want to get the format as `202009`

Comment: Please provide the dataframe schema.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `16-9-2020` as a string, you can convert it to date and then to your format like this:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"delivery_date": "16-9-2020"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.withColumn(
    "result", F.date_format(F.to_date("delivery_date", "dd-M-yyyy"), "yyyyMM")
)
```

Result:

```
+-------------+------+                                                          
|delivery_date|result|
+-------------+------+
|    16-9-2020|202009|
+-------------+------+
```